# How does Perl decide which order to evaluate terms in an expression?

Tags: perl, operator-precedence, associativity

Given the code:

```
my $x = 1;

$x = $x * 5 * ($x += 5);
```

I would expect `$x` to be `180`:

```
$x = $x * 5 * ($x += 5); #$x = 1
$x = $x * 5 * 6;         #$x = 6
$x = 30 * 6;
$x = 180;
180;
```

But instead it is `30`; however, if I change the ordering of the terms:

```
$x = ($x += 5) * $x * 5;
```

I do get `180`.  The reason I am confused is that [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) says very plainly:

> A TERM has the highest precedence in Perl.  They include variables,
>   quote and quote-like operators, **any expression in parentheses**, and any
>   function whose arguments are parenthesized.

Since `($x += 5)` is in parentheses, it should be a term, and therefore executed first, regardless of the ordering of the expression.

Comment: You know, having learned C first, I never do stuff like this and expect it to work the way I think it ought to work: http://c-faq.com/expr/index.html ;-)

Comment: I too came from ANSI C, and yeah, this isn't code I would write, it is me trying to make sure I understand precedence in Perl before I explain it to someone else.  Using side-effects like this is a major no-no, but still legal in Perl.  In ANSI C, if you had more than one side-effect in an expression the results were undefined, in Perl side-effects are better defined, but still a really bad idea.

Comment: I once made a lovely post about this to comp.lang.perl.misc, and have never been able to find it again.

Comment: My advice:  don't do this.  Perl allows it, but it's a serious readability problem.  You do not want to have to work on code where you have to carefully parse an expression to figure out what it means.

Comment: @David Thornley It isn't a matter of doing it.  It is a matter of understanding it.  I am writing an article that involves precedence and associativity of operators and I don't want to state anything that is false.  This means I need to understand what Perl does much better than is normally necessary; hence the bad, but legal, code as I look for inconsistencies in my understanding.

Answer (score 16):

The act of typing out the question yielded the answer to me: terms have the highest precedence.  That means that the `$x` in the first chunk of code is evaluated and yields `1`, then `5` is evaluated and yields `5`, then `($x += 5)` is evaluate and yields `6` (with a side-effect of setting `$x` to `6`):

```
$x = $x * 5 * ($x += 5);
address of $x = $x * 5 * ($x += 5); #evaluate $x as an lvalue
address of $x = 1 * 5 * ($x += 5);  #evaluate $x as an rvalue
address of $x = 1 * 5 * ($x += 5);  #evaluate 5
address of $x = 1 * 5 * 6;          #evaluate ($x += 5), $x is now 6
address of $x = 1 * 5 * 6;          #evaluate 1 * 5
address of $x = 5 * 6;              #evaluate 1 * 5
address of $x = 30;                 #evaluate 5 * 6
30;                                 #evaluate address of $x = 30
```

Similarly, the second example reduces like this:

```
$x = ($x += 5) * $x * 5; 
address of $x = ($x += 5) * $x * 5; #evaluate $x as an lvalue
address of $x = 6 * $x * 5;         #evaluate ($x += 5), $x is now 6
address of $x = 6 * 6 * 5;          #evaluate $x as an rvalue
address of $x = 6 * 6 * 5;          #evaluate 5
address of $x = 36 * 5;             #evaluate 6 * 6
address of $x = 180;                #evaluate 36 * 5
180;                                #evaluate $x = 180
```

Comment: Correct. What was tripping you up wasn't precedence but order of evaluation. The `($x += 5)` isn't evaluated until after the first multiplication takes place. The parentheses only serve to ensure that the `+=` happens before the (second) multiplication. In this case, that prevents a syntax error because multiplication has a higher precedence than assignment and the result of multiplication isn't a valid lvalue.

Answer (score 10):

Whenever I have confusion about stuff like this I first pull out [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), and then if I'm still not sure, or want to see how a particular block of code will get executed, I use [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html):

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p,-q,-sC
my $x = 1;
$x = $x * 5 * ($x += 5);
```

<kbd>^D</kbd>

gives:

```
(my $x = 1);
($x = (($x * 5) * ($x += 5)));
- syntax OK
```

So substituting values at each stage gives:

```
($x = (($x * 5) * ($x += 5)));
($x = ((1 * 5) * ($x += 5)));
($x = ((5) * (6))); # and side-effect: $x is now 6
($x = (5 * 6));
($x = (30));
($x = 30);
$x = 30;
```

So the fact that $x was temporarily set to 6 doesn't really affect anything, because the earlier value (1) was already substituted into the expression, and by the end of the expression it is now 30.

Comment: Interesting. But it brings up the question where the parens around $x*5 come from.

Comment: `*` is a binary operator that evaluates left-to-right, so `$x * $y * $z` would evaluate as `(($x * $y) * $z)`.

Comment: Ether, *evaluating* left to right isn't the same as *associating* left to right. Even if `*` associated right to left, it could still be evaluated left to right: first evaluate $x and store its value in a temporary; then evaluate $y, then $z; next multiply them and multiply the result with the saved temporary value from $x. Precedence doesn't determine evaluation order, unless you can find some documentation that says otherwise for Perl. (Java, for instance, is defined to evaluate from left to right, even if a right-hand operator has higher precedence.)

Comment: (What I mean to say is that Java evaluates *operands* from left to right. *Operators* are evaluated according to their precedence rules.)

Comment: @Rob: yes, you're absolutely right. Thanks for correcting my muddy wording! Clarity of thought means clarity of code.. :)

Answer (score 4):

`$x` by itself is also a TERM. Since it is encountered first (in your first example), it is evaluated first.

Answer (score 2):

The associativity of the `*` operator is leftward, so the left most term is always evaluated before the right most term. Other operators, such as `**` are right associative and would have evaluated `($x += 5)` before the rest of the statement.

Comment: You're conflating associativity, precedence, and evaluation order. They're three separate things.